# Соединить сайт на WordPress с CRM

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт на Вордпресс, сайт фактически состоит из одной главной страницы. Сейчас понадобилось добавить на сайт ссылки Вход и Регистрация, которые должны вести на некую CRM, в которой пользователи должны иметь возможность создать свой аккаунт (зарегистрироваться), войти в него и либо создавать, либо брать заказы (два типа пользователей). Ищу варианты, как это лучше реализовать? Отдельная CRM? Если да, то какая? Или для этих целей будет достаточно какого-нибудь CRM WordPress плагина? Если да, то какого?

Comment: Причём тут ВП? Определись с CRM для начала. А она выбирается не по ссылкам с сайта, а по задачам.

Comment: Для ВП тоже есть плагины с функционалом CRM. Возможно, для этих задач плагина будет достаточно, но я с ними не работала, возможно, кто-то работал и может подсказать.

Answer (score 0):

Звучит очень размыто. 
Регистрация и вход есть на том же самом Wordpress. А реализацию заказов для авторизированных пользователей уже нужно продумывать. CRM  тут нужна в том случае если это большая база продуктов/услуг и к этим услугам должен бить полный контроль типа того же СМС информирования и т д. А если это просто создать заказ и обработать его, но только для авторизированных пользователей то можно и на WP. 
Если нужна та же CRM посмотрите в сторону Bitrix